# Printing dataGridView in Tables (vb2010)

Tags: vb.net

i'm new to vb programming. i'm using vb2010 I'm doing a database application now. It works fine. But i have to add another task. That is to print the data on the DGV in table form. I've done a lot of research about this but haven't found it. Any help or response will be highly appreciated.

i'm sorry, here is my Code: It works but it prints just a black document.

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\IT-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MaterialSectionIS\MaterialSectionIS\My Project\materialsInventory.accdb"

    Dim MyPrintDocument As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument
    Dim MyDataGridViewPrinter As DataGridViewPrinter
    Dim MyPrintDialog As PrintDialog = New PrintDialog()

    MyPrintDialog.AllowCurrentPage = False
    MyPrintDialog.AllowPrintToFile = False
    MyPrintDialog.AllowSelection = False
    MyPrintDialog.AllowSomePages = True
    MyPrintDialog.PrintToFile = False
    MyPrintDialog.ShowHelp = False
    MyPrintDialog.ShowNetwork = False
    'Dim commdata As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM metal WHERE itemCodeM = @tbItemCodeMetal", myConnection)
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [metal]", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "metal")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    If MyPrintDialog.ShowDialog() <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Return False

    MyPrintDocument.DocumentName = "metal"
    MyPrintDocument.PrinterSettings = MyPrintDialog.PrinterSettings
    MyPrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings = MyPrintDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings
    MyPrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(40, 40, 40, 40)

    If MessageBox.Show("Do you want the report to be centered on the page", "METAL - Center on Page", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        MyDataGridViewPrinter = New DataGridViewPrinter(DataGridView1, MyPrintDocument, True, True, "metal", New Font("Tahoma", 18, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Color.Black, True)
    Else
        MyDataGridViewPrinter = New DataGridViewPrinter(DataGridView1, MyPrintDocument, False, True, "metal", New Font("Tahoma", 18, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point), Color.Black, True)
    End If

    Return True
End Function


Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim more As Boolean

    Try
        more = MyDataGridViewPrinter.DrawDataGridView(e.Graphics)
        If more Then e.HasMorePages = True
    Catch Ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message & vbCrLf & Ex.StackTrace, MyConstants.CaptionFehler, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MyPrintDocument As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument

    If SetupThePrinting() Then
        Dim MyPrintPreviewDialog As PrintPreviewDialog = New PrintPreviewDialog()
        MyPrintPreviewDialog.Document = MyPrintDocument
        MyPrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub





Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim MyPrintDocument As PrintDocument = New PrintDocument
    If SetupThePrinting() Then MyPrintDocument.Print()
End Sub
```

Comment: When You wrote print - did You think printing on the paper (using printer)? Or how to pass values from datagridview into table (presume datatable)  or...? Show us some code, what You done so far. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Check out this link.  Note that the original code is for a `DataGrid` control but later in the thread is the equivalent for a `DataGridView`.  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?356115-DataGridPrinter-A-class-to-print-data-grid-in-a-nicely-formatted-way

Comment: One button print will be difficult. I just have my users select all, copy, and paste into Excel/Word table.

Comment: i'm sorry, here is my Code: It works but it prints just a black document.